# Background mode and local notifications

Tags: ios, background

My app is going to be a lot of time in a background mode.

I want to display a local notification on some events (so I have to check if the event has happened before displaying a local notification).

The check if an event has occurred is very simple (and takes very short time).

Is is possible, when my app is in background mode, to check if event has occurred, and send a local notification ?

There is an option to perform a finite-length tasks, but I need this to happen every x minutes, so I don't know if it's what I need.

Comment: Since you app is suspended when in the background how are you planning to check the event? Only if you app is a VOIP, music player, location tracker of accessory app can your app really run in the background. You supposed finite-length tasks will not work since if will be a couple of minutes from when the app enters the background state,

Comment: Yep, this is the reason I asked this question, to know if there is something I can do. I thought it's might be possible if the process I need to do is taking very short time, and my app get about ~3 min in background, I can "activate" it, and after some seconds to "release" it. after 10 min "wake" it again and so on.. That way I can repeat this until Ill waste the 3 minutes

Comment: I would not suggest this, since it will drain the battery and is a miss use of the API which might get you rejected. You can try to register for background fetch, but other the a real push notification I don't see how this can be solved correctly.

Comment: I guess you're right. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, write it as an answer and I'll accept it as the right one